# How to sort categories by sections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I sort the categories by their respective sections?

Like the "Languages" section has English, Arabic, Spanish etc. I want to display section names as headings, and their categories as checkboxes. Here is my code.

**app/models/profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end
```

**app/models/category.rb**

```
class category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :profiles, through: :categorizations
end
```

**app/models/section.rb**

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

**app/views/profiles/_form.html.rb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= hidden_field_tag "profile[category_ids][]", nil %>
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "profile[category_ids][]", category.id, @profile.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %><br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks James, I ll follow your updated style to post questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section should be criteria of outter iteration if you want sort categories by section. 
Try below snippet.

```
<% Section.all.each do |section| %>
    <% section.categories.each do |category| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "profile[category_ids][]", category.id, @profile.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```